# Why am I getting a 404 message from my C# webserver even after setting the appropriate URL ACL?

Tags: c#, networking, netsh

I have a web server built with HttpListener in C#. It is using a specific path on port 80 for GET requests being called from another C# application. It works between my development machine and a virtual machine. I set it up on another computer, and I start getting 404 responses from the server. I have the following command run to open the port and path:

**netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Server HTTP" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80**

**netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/svrpath/ user=%USERDOMAIN%%USERNAME% listen=yes**

I cannot figure out why I keep getting 404 errors when I call a simple get to this server. If I run the server on my development machine, it works fine and the GET returns the expected json string. I have even turned off the the firewall on both sides and it continues to give me 404 errors. I have run the get command from a web browser with the same result.

I have also tried changing the user on the "add urlacl" command to values such as Everyone and Administrators to no avail.

Searching around Google has not given me any solution to this and I am looking for anyone who has any idea what could cause such a problem. All machines in question are running Windows 10 build 1709 and are connected on the local network. I'm sure there is something dumb I have missed somewhere, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Have you verified that nothing else is already listening on that port, such as Skype?

Comment: I have nothing else installed on the computer which should be using this (Skype removed). I checked with netstat and I see what looks like my process using port 80 and an entry for svchost.exe using port 80.

Comment: Okay, so I decided to restart the system and reinstall the software and re-execute all the setup commands -- and it magically all works now. But I still don't understand why.

Comment: Whatever service process svchost was hosting was seemingly listening on that port.

Comment: How do I find out what was behind that svchost?

Comment: Find it in the details tab of Task Manager by process id, right-click > go to services.

Comment: Maybe you need HTTPS (secure) instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

At this point all I can conclude is another process was locking the port so that my application was unable to respond to the requests. A restart and full re-installation of the program (including re-running all netsh commands) solved the problem and it has not recurred since doing that.